# Single Sign On using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I am trying to use Single sign on in my application. I am referring [this link](http://codetheory.in/rails-devise-omniauth-sso/) for the implementation.

As per their implementation, they have two different application

- Provider (used devise for the sign up/in)
- Client (without devise)

and it is working fine. I am able to login and logout.

Now I am trying to implement same scenario in my applications. I have following application (They are already built and used devise for sign in / up)

- Provider (used devise for the sign up/in)
- Client (used devise)

I kept that Provider application as it is (As per the [provider](https://github.com/rishabhp/sso-rails-provider).)

But when I tried to implement this in my client getting following error

```
Could not find devise mapping for path "/auth/sso/callback?code=c6fb99e3d8c6c2545f5a99c6385d7e76&response_type=code&state=7e33b2653946fc3c896e3b8091cfd17c0d6ddd5cfafd16c4".
```

For this I made following changes

**omniauth.rb**

```
APP_ID = 'refe123456789'
APP_SECRET = 'refer123456789'

CUSTOM_PROVIDER_URL = 'http://localhost:3000'

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :sso, APP_ID, APP_SECRET
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}

  # omniauth
  get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/auth/failure' => 'sessions#failure'
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2'
```

How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: hi there - did you manage to get a solution to this problem?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I tired this link https://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/

Comment: thx - i actually foudn that same link on google :)

Comment: What about the following:

- http://www.binarywebpark.com/oauth-2-tutorial/
- http://www.binarywebpark.com/setting-oauth-provider-ruby-rails-doorkeeper-devise/
- http://www.binarywebpark.com/oauth-client-application-testing-rails/